# How to add a windows firewall port exception on a remote machine using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-firewall

I am writing a script to do a silent install of a program on a windows machine using powershell. However I am hitting an issue where the program does not properly setup the machine's windows firewall settings. Is their a way for a powershell script that is being remotely executed to add a firewall port exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have remoting enabled on remote computer ( `Enable-PSRemoting` ).
Enter in the remote session ( `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName remotecomputername` )
Then you can use the native commandline [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771046%28WS.10%29.aspx) to Enable/Disable Windows firewall using:

```
netsh firewall set opmode
                   [ mode = ] ENABLE|DISABLE
                   [ [ exceptions = ] ENABLE|DISABLE
                   [ profile = ] CURRENT|DOMAIN|STANDARD|ALL
                   [ interface = ] name ]
```